# separating with a newline

Tags: command-line

I am using Ubuntu with window (WSL). How do I separate my sentence in a newline without executing the command. I have tried <kbd>shift-Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-enter</kbd>, Perl -lne and so on. Please check the attached image to know exactly what I mean.

[image]

Comment: please fix your question, the screenshot does not show. In General, please don't post screenshots when you could post it as text ... paste text and format as code is usually better)

Comment: The answers below make reasonable assumptions about what you are trying to achieve, but it is not clear from your question what you are trying to do? I do not see the sentence (that you want to split into multiple lines) in the screen shot above. Would you please clarify further by editing your question? If you can give an example of the sentence, how it currently appears, and how you would like it to appear, that will be very helpful in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash `\` at the end of each line and press Enter. At the last line press Enter (without including a backslash obviously).

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes you want to have a line break as part of a command argument, so that the command receives it. If you just want to split/wrap a long command line without having the line break appear in any argument, have a look at [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1167680/367990).*

You can have line breaks as part of a single argument inside 'quoted' strings, like this:

```bsh
$ echo 'This is some
> multiline argument'
```

`$` represents your normal shell prompt (PS1), whereas `>` is the secondary prompt (PS2) that indicates you're still editing the same command.

Don't forget the closing quotation mark at the end of your multiline string.

If you want a line break in your argument without breaking your command line, you can also use e.g. `$'\n'` as a literal line break.

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answers is totally fine, they may not helped you. So if you want to give multi-line input to some program running from a shell (like bash)  you have more options (beyond typing the lines one-by-one)

1) Save the line to a file and pipe it as input:

```
$ cat somefile | ssss-combine -t 3
```

2) Compose the file with a technique mentioned in previous answers like:

```
$ echo 'passwd-04-1e8c
> passwd-05-dc8f
> passwd-10-2910' | ssss-combine -t 3
```

3) Same as `2` in a oneliner:

```
for i in passwd-04-1e8c passwd-05-dc8f passwd-10-2910;do echo $i;done | ssss-combine -t 3
```

I have to mention that is not recommended to write secrets (or parts of secrets) in a command line. Try to avoid always this if possible.